# OrderedDict comparison inconsistency

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison, equality, ordereddict

I noticed this striking inconsistency in the relationship between `dict`s and `OrderedDict`s.  From the docs:

> Equality tests between OrderedDict objects are order-sensitive and are implemented as `list(od1.items())==list(od2.items())`. Equality tests between `OrderedDict` objects and other Mapping objects are order-insensitive like regular dictionaries. This allows `OrderedDict` objects to be substituted anywhere a regular dictionary is used.

This is a problem, because it violates the *transitive property of equality*, as shown below.

**My questions**: is there good justification for this (other than "...allows OrderedDict objects to be substituted...")?  Are there any other standard python types which violate the *transitive property of equality*?

The following tests should all be equivalent, but they are not:

```
od1 = OrderedDict([(1,1), (2,2)])
od2 = OrderedDict([(2,2), (1,1)])
d = dict(od1)
d   == od1 == od2 # False
od1 == d   == od2 # True ...
od1 == od2 == d   # False
```

It seems to me it should have been the case that either:

1. The collection is *ordered*, i.e. order is part of its *value*, in which case comparing with an unordered `dict` should not be defined (same as comparing a `list` with a `set`)
2. The collection is *not ordered*, in which case `od1==od2`. The order can still be maintained for iterating, but is not considered part of *the value*.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @martineau I didn't tag it because afaik this applies to all versions

Comment: I asked because of the "...and other Mapping objects are order-insensitive like regular dictionaries" part of the quote in your question — regular dictionaries started officially preserving order like `OrderedDict`s do in Python 3.7 (and unofficially in cPython 3.6) — so it seems relevant.

Comment: The two dictionaries are equal because the order of their contents is different, just like two list with the same elements in a different order would be.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke (was very late), What I meant to say was: The two dictionaries are unequal because the order of their contents is different, just like two lists with the same elements in them but in a different order would be (unequal).

Comment: @martineau, yet, the two dicts are **equal**, in all python versions.  Try it: `dict([(2,2), (1,1)]) == dict([(1,1), (2,2)])`

Comment: You're right — I was mistaken. The 3.0 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) says "Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (**regardless of ordering**)". You're also correct that regular `dict`s and `OrderedDict`s behave inconsistently in this respect. The latter's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) explains: "Equality tests between `OrderedDict` objects **are order-sensitive** and are implemented as `list(od1.items())==list(od2.items())`".

Comment: My guess is the disparity is likely for backwards-compatibly — in Python 2.x the documentation says "Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs" (and making order start to matter since it's now preserved might break too much existing code). There are also some other differences between `dict`s and `OrderedDict`s.